# EXCEL unique values from multiple seperated columns into one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, export-to-excel

```
Table 1  table 2  table 3
a                 a
e                 a
d                 g
t                 d
e                 c
e                 c
```

I want to have a results

```
Table 7
a
c
d
t
g
e
```

but theses two table is not next to each other...
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

`TEXTJOIN()` and `FILTERXML()` can do it. Try-

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,A2:C7)&"</s></t>","//s[not(preceding::*=.)]")
```

[image]

Comment: Details about `FILTERXML()` here from JvdV https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/5514747

Answer (score 0):

Using `VTSACK()` Function,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Formula used in cell **E2**

```
=UNIQUE(VSTACK(A2:A7,C2:C7))
```

Please note **[VSTACK()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vstack-function-a4b86897-be0f-48fc-adca-fcc10d795a9c)** Function currently available in **O365 Insiders Beta Channel Version**, arrays can be non-contiguous irregular but needs to be vertical.

---

Also since you have non-contiguous ranges, `TEXTJOIN()` can also perform the same by wrapping it within `FILTERXML()` Function.

Formula used in cell **F2**

```
=UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,A2:A7,C2:C7)&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

**Note:** Since you have not mentioned your Excel Version, assumption made that you are using **O365** - updated version.